# Why the table column is not deleted after changing the db_schema.xml?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I described the table with declarative schema (Magento 2.3):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="mi_declarative_schema_test" resource="default" comment="Declarative schema test">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="id" identity="true" comment="ID Auto Increment" />
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="name" length="1024" nullable="false" comment="Name" />
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="id" />
        </constraint>
    </table>
</schema>
```

I did *setup:upgrade*, the table was created, everything is ok. I add the columns,do an upgrade - they are added ok. But when I delete columns from xml, they are not deleted from the table. The instruction 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html says it is enough to delete or comment out the column line. 
Magento connects to the DB with root access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in whitelist https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/migration-commands.html#create-whitelist

You have to regenerate whitelist for your module every time you delete something in your XML.

Answer (score 2):

I have added delete column sample code for name column. Magento added delete column for disabled="true" .

```
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
<table name="mi_declarative_schema_test" resource="default" comment="Declarative schema test">
    <column xsi:type="int" name="id" identity="true" comment="ID Auto Increment" />
    <column xsi:type="varchar" name="name" length="1024" nullable="false" comment="Name" disabled="true"/>
    <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
        <column name="id" />
    </constraint>
</table>
</schema>
```

Comment: Documentation says "The following example removes the date_closed column by deleting its column node". disabled=true is for deleting column from another module. Anyway, both of these methods don't delete the column from MySQL table

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the whitelist for your module. You can do this by below commands

```
php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=[Vendor_Module]
```

And then after run upgrade command.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Thanks